# Is it possible to make photo popups?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4

ArcMap 10.4.1.5686. What I am asking may be impossible, but it sure would be sassy. I went to a site and GPS marked areas where people had been creating ATV trails. I want to link photos of the damage to the points in such a way that if you mouse over the point, a photo pops up. I have tried the adding photos to attribute table thing, but when I click identify, info just pops up, and then I have to click again to see the photo. I'd like to streamline this if at all possible.

Comment: are you trying to do this within ArcMap or ArcGIS  Online?

Comment: If you're in arcmap, and you have the photos as attachments, use the HTMLPopUp tool, not the identify. It'll show the image. (its 2 to the right of the identify button)

Comment: I am using Arcmap. Is there a way to do it with just mousing?

Comment: Also, the html popup doesn't work for that. I used arc catalog to add a pictures area to the attribute table for the waypoints. Then I clicked start editing, went into the attribute table, and added a photo.